# UWP Semantic Zoom, ListView, VisualState

Tags: template10

`<SemanticZoom x:Name="Zoom" >
                <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                    <ListView Name="HotelInList"
                              IsItemClickEnabled="False"
                              Style="{StaticResource HotelListViewStyle}"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HotelListItemContainerStyle}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource HotelViewSource}}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HotelListItemTemplate}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                                <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="DetailVisualState" />
                            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ListView.GroupStyle>`

The interactivity snippet above doesn't work.  It will complain about how HotelInList doesn't contain a visual state named DetailVisualState, which is left out for brevity for now, but it is a visualstate above part of the rootlayout grid

Would nesting inside the SemanticZoom block the EventTriggerBehavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
        <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="DetailVisualState" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ThisPage}" />
   </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>`

Where ThisPage is the x:Name of the actual page, which forces the interaction to look down the resource tree and find from the the available resources the visualstate you requested.